# Clearing jQuery Mobile Multiple Select Lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page element

```
<select name="geoLocationIndicatorClassID" id="int_geoLocationIndicatorClassID" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
```

With the  elements generated dynamically

```
$('#int_geoLocationIndicatorClassID').append($('<option></option>').val(results.rows.item(i).geoLocationIndicatorClassID).html(results.rows.item(i).geoLocationIndicatorClassName));
```

Where results is an Sql object.

My problem is clearing the list when the user has submitted data.

I have tried

```
$('#int_geoLocationIndicatorClassID a').each(function(){ 
$(this).removeClass('ui-checkbox-on').addClass('ui-checkbox-off');
});

$('#int_geoLocationIndicatorClassID :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
$(selected).attr("selected", false);
$(selected).removeClass('ui-checkbox-on').addClass('ui-checkbox-off');
});

$('#int_geoLocationIndicatorClassID').selectmenu('refresh');
```

and

```
$("#int_geoLocationIndicatorClassID option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

But this does not clear selections. Is there a better way of clearing dynamically generated multiple selects?

Comment: have you tried to use .prop()?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: $("#int_geoLocationIndicatorClassID option:selected").prop("selected", false);

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#int_geoLocationIndicatorClassID").val([]).selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

The true on the **[refresh()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh)** method forces jQM to rebuild the widget after setting the selected vals to an empty array.

Comment: Thank You. That worked a treat. I guess the rebuild is required because the list is built dynamically i.e. after the page is loaded.